# Confused on installation

Tags: system-installation

I downloaded elementaryOS on my Linuxmint desktop and burned the iso to my USB-2 pendrive. I don't want to install it over Linuxmint. I have a USB-3 pendrive I want to install ElementaryOS on. I didn't see an option for this when I booted from the USB-2 drive. I'm missing something -- not sure what to do.

Update: apr 18 2022:

I had the USB with the iso plugged in, and I had the 65GB usb (that I want to put Elementary on) plugged in too. It hangs right here:

> INFO: starting extracting step  INFO: Extracting
> /cdrom/casper/filesystem.squashfs DEBUG: "unsquashfs" "-f" "-d"
> "tmp/distinst.Q5bl9tzlZmEh" "/cdrom/casper - filesystem.squashfs"
> ERROR: extracting error: archive extraction failed with status: exit
> status: 1

I reformatted the usb with the iso and put MX-21 iso on it. Then I installed this onto the flash drive without a problem. Then today, I reformatted the 64 GB drive and installed the Elementary iso on a DVD-R disk, and used it to install elementary - but I get the same error.

It seems whatever Casper is, could be the problem, or it's linked to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have not yet used Elementary OS, but do you have the the USB3 pendrive plugged in while you are trying to install? I'm assuming that this would be necessary for you to install on it. Most Linux distros give you a list of all the devices that they can find which you can install on, if you have your USB3 pendrive plugged in and it is not shown on the list, then it would likely require a lot more work to install on it if it is possible at all.

Answer (score -1):

I've gotten this error a million times. Installing eOS has never gone smoothly for me.
I'd say redownload the iso and make sure you do the checksum for it.
If thats all good, then just run and rerun the installer again and again until you don't get the casper error and it works. That's how I have to do it any time I want to put eOS on a computer.